# Where can I store site-wide variables in Rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am new to Rails and come from a ColdFusion background, where we would store global / site-wide variables in the 'application' scope. This persists the variable across any view or controller. Does Rails 4 have an equivalent functionality for this type of thing?

The site-wide variable won't typically change often so it doesn't need protecting in any way.

For example, in my situation, I want to store the website's domain name. One for testing and one for live environments. Localhost for development and xxxxxx.com for production.

Any tips or pointers would help. I have Googled this extensively and solutions seem to be far too complicated to achieve what seems to be such a trivial task. What's the best elegant solution for Rails 4?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The simplest, basic and default way is to use the `Rails.application.config` store.

```
Rails.application.config.my_config = 'foo'
```

You can assign a config in your environment:

```
# application.rb
module MyApp
  class Application < Rails::Application
    config.my_config = 'foo'
  end
end
```

and read it with

```
Rails.application.config.my_config
# => 'foo'
```

This approach works well for very simple applications, but if you want something more advanced there are several gems available.

I'm currently using [`SimpleConfig`](https://github.com/lukeredpath/simpleconfig). The main advantages are:

- per-environment configuration. You can configure default configurations for the application, then override defaults with environment specific configurations
- `local.rb` file for custom overrides
- `capistrano`-like configuration style
- it works nicely with the [`dotenv`](https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv) gem, very useful to avoid storing sensitive credentials in your repo.

Comment: Thanks, your first suggestion worked for me. You may want to note on your answer though, that in order for the variables to be picked up, you need to restart Rails.

Answer (score 9):

This sounds like a perfect example for configuration values stored in `config/environments/production.rb` and `config/environments/development.rb`. Just store any value there:

```
config.my_special_value = 'val'
```

And access it in your application like this:

```
Rails.application.config.my_special_value
```

Always the value of your environment is active.

If you just want to have a „global“ value, store it in your application controller. All your view controllers are derived from your app controller, so you can save any value there as an instance or class variable:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  MY_CONSTANT_VALUE = "foo"
end

class MyViewController < ApplicationController
  def index
    raise MY_CONSTANT_VALUE.inspect
  end
end
```

You also could implement an helper:

```
# app/helpers/application_helper.rb
module ApplicationHelper
  FOO = "bar"
end

# app/controllers/foo_controller.rb
class FooController < ApplicationController
  def index
    raise FOO
  end
end
```

Comment: Global constants are global and are accessible everywhere. In your example, you can just use initializers, not need to rely on classes or modules.

Answer (score 4):

I can recommend good method to store variable. I use this on production

Passwords can be stored easier to `.env` file
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jbcAO.png]

like this

```
#Root dir create file ".env"
PASSWORD=123456
```

and load password

```
#Somewhere in app
ENV['PASSWORD'] #=> 123456
```

it works I hope will help you

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use [gem figaro](https://github.com/laserlemon/figaro)

write your variables in **config/application.yml**

```
HELLO: world
development:
  HELLO: developers
production:
  HELLO: users
```

Then you can fetch

```
ENV["HELLO"]
```

Answer (score 0):

In rails there is gem named as

```
gem 'dotenv-rails'
```

By using it we can assign the variables to system level and used in application.

By using simple steps
First create a simple filed in system level at any place with named extension .env

```
//in application.rb        
require 'dotenv'
Dotenv.load('path-of-your-file.env')
```

And restart your application

Source
[Please got the link for the desscription of dot env gem](https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv)