# Storing some application settings in Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails

There is the following task: My app has got one variable with name 'delivery_time'; this variable can be changed through admin panel. I think it's not a good way to store it in some database table. How can I store it in configs or anything else? May be I should store it in db yet?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20857886/where-can-i-store-site-wide-variables-in-rails-4

Answer (score 1):

Basically for static settings we use following gem

https://github.com/railsjedi/rails_config

so this gem will generate following file

```
config/settings.yml
```

you can define your variable(my_config) in this yml file. and use it throughout your application as follows:

```
Settings.my_config
```

Or you can use any similar gems

Answer (score 1):

You can easily store settings in the config file like this:

1. Create `config.yml` and store your settings

   `delivery_time: '...'`
2. Add this config to initializers/load_config.rb

   ```
   require 'ostruct'
   require 'yaml'

   app_config = YAML.load_file(File.join(::Rails.root, 'config', 'config.yml'))[Rails.env]
   ::AppConfig = OpenStruct.new app_config
   ```

And you can call it `AppConfig.delivery_time` anywhere in the project

Answer (score 0):

you can use PStore that implements a file based persistence mechanism based on a Hash.

OR 
yaml based approach