# How can I setup a variable in the application_controller and have is show in my footer?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to setup a variable in my `application_controller.rb` for version info, and I'd like for it to show up in the footer. I assumed this would be simple but its not working for me.

Here is what I have in application_controller.rb:

```
@version_info = '2.2'
```

Here is my footer in the application.html.erb:

```
<div class="footer">
  <div class="one_half">
    <div class="copyright">
      <p>© Copyright 2014 MY COMPANY | Dashboard version <%= @version_info %></p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="one_half_last">
    <div class="footer_menu">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I've tried the same variable in other controller/view combos and it works fine. Is it something to do with the `application_controller`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do us `before_filter` or `before_action` for rails 4:

```
before_filter :set_default_variables

def set_default_variables
  @version_info = '2.2'
end
```

Comment: You are welcome, you may look at this [alternative solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20857886/where-can-i-store-site-wide-variables-in-rails-4).