# Global mutable variable in Ruby on Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm building a site and want to store two variables: the target and current progress for a fundraising campaign. The organization may change the target every year, and of course will need to change the current progress. I could create a model but this seems like overkill as I would never create more than one object. Is there an easy (and standard) way to do this?

I'm new to rails and I've looked for answers to this question but haven't found anything exceptionally helpful - I apologize if this is a common issue. Other answers depict how to store site wide variables when you do not want to edit them, but here I'd like to be able to update them as often as required.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where can I store site-wide variables in Rails 4?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20857886/where-can-i-store-site-wide-variables-in-rails-4)

Comment: @MarsAtomic Those answers don't seem to say anything about updating the variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This can be an answer for you:**

1. Create a model for site information probably you already have.
2. Add two fields called `targe` and `progress`.
3. If you calculate progress programatically then no need to add field.
4. Then make view where they can update target and progress and write logic to update that field only.
   Programmatically there is not a good idea other than this. I think.